# How to update taxonomy field in a node?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, nodes

```
node_load($nid);
$node->mytaxonomyfield['und'][0]['tid']=$data;
node_save($nid)
```

my corresponding terms : online,offline,pre-online  and the corresponding tid : 1,2,3

my question : what the program will be that changing the field data by words instead of tid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (at least not directly). Don't forget that multiple taxonomy terms may have the same name so they need to be identified by their `tid` or you'd get clashes.

You have a couple of options to load a taxonomy term by name, but for each you'll need to know the `vid` of the term's vocabulary.

The first option is to use the deprecated `$conditions` parameter of the [`taxonomy_term_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple/7) function:

```
$terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple(array(), array('name' => 'online', 'vid' => $vid));
$first_term = array_shift($terms);
$tid = $first_term->tid;
```

As you can see it's limited to loading just one term at a time.

The second (much better) way is to use an [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7):

```
$terms = array(
  'online',
  'offline',
  'pre-online'
);

$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->propertyCondition('vid', $vid)
  ->propertyCondition('name', $terms, 'IN');

$results = $query->execute();

if (isset($results['taxonomy_term'])) {
  // Get an array of tids
  $tids = array_keys($results['taxonomy_term']);
}
```

That way you can load multiple terms in one go, and take advantage of non-SQL field storage solutions if you need to.

If you're worried about speed you could also go directly into the `taxonomy_term` table to get this data; but I don't advise doing this unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: thx a lot,my problem is fixed!